# How does one extract the principle component scores to be used in follow up statistics using FAMD?

Tags: python, r, factor-analysis

I do know how to get the eigenvalues, contributions, and coordinates, but where can i get the PC scores? These values are the ones that are typically produces in PCA which you use instead of the original variables that went into dimensionality reduction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Sklearn Python Library has a [function that can do this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)